# @ManyToMany saving relations is available only one time in one direction

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I will try create @ManyToMany relation in my SpringBoot application.
I use JPARespository, I create 2 models:

**User**

```
@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany//(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @LazyCollection(value = LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_groups",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "users_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "groups_id")
    )
    private Set<UGroup> groups;

    public User() {
        this.groups = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public void addGroup(UGroup uGroup) {
        this.groups.add(uGroup);
        uGroup.users.add(this);
    }

    public void removeGroup(UGroup uGroup) {
        this.groups.remove(uGroup);
        uGroup.users.remove(this);
    }
}
```

**UGroups**

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "UGroup")
@Table(name = "groups")
public class UGroup {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groups", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @LazyCollection(value = LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    public Set<User> users;

    public UGroup() {
        this.users = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public void addUser(User user) {
        this.users.add(user);
        user.getGroups().add(this);
    }

    public void removeUser(User user) {
        this.users.remove(user);
        user.getGroups().remove(this);
    }
}
```

I load start data via ***DataConfiguration*** class:

```
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Damian");
        userRepository.save(user);

        user = new User();
        user.setName("Marta");
        userRepository.save(user);

        user = new User();
        user.setName("Natalia");
        userRepository.save(user);

        UGroup uGroup = new UGroup();
        uGroup.setName("Mieszkanie");
        uGroup = uGroupRepository.save(uGroup);

        user = userRepository.findById(1).get();
        user.addGroup(uGroup);
        user = userRepository.save(user);

        // unable to execute
        /*
        user = userRepository.findById(2).get();
        user.addGroup(uGroup);
        user = userRepository.save(user);
         */

        // unable to execute 2
        /*
        uGroup = uGroupRepository.findById(4).get();
        uGroup.addUser(userRepository.findById(3).get());
        uGroup = uGroupRepository.save(uGroup);
         */
    }
```

When i execute only insert group for 1 user all is good.
Although when I try execute insert group for 1 and 2 users or insert 3 user for group it cause `java.lang.StackOverflowError: null` exception.

I don know where is error. Can anyone help me and explain me where and why I should change something?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to mention the join table and columns to make your manyTomany work

Comment: If I know correctly @JoinTable is not necessary, but I tried to use it. Still not working properly, the same exception.

Comment: Post the error/exception you are getting with the stacktrace so that it will be easier to explain/debug the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Join Table,it it possible to map ManyToMany bidirectional relation.These are the modified entity classes

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Set<UGroup> getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }

    public void setGroups(Set<UGroup> groups) {
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @LazyCollection(value = LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private Set<UGroup> groups=new HashSet<UGroup>();

    public User() {
    }

    public void addGroup(UGroup uGroup) {
        this.groups.add(uGroup);
        uGroup.users.add(this);
    }

    public void removeGroup(UGroup uGroup) {
        this.groups.remove(uGroup);
        uGroup.users.remove(this);
    }
}

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity(name = "UGroup")
@Table(name = "groups")
public class UGroup {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_GROUP_MAP" ,joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="GROUP_ID",referencedColumnName = "ID")
            ,inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID",referencedColumnName = "ID"))
    @LazyCollection(value = LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    public Set<User> users=new HashSet<>();

    public UGroup() {
    }

    public void addUser(User user) {
        this.users.add(user);
        user.addGroup(this);
    }

    public void removeUser(User user) {
        this.users.remove(user);
        user.removeGroup(this);
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

For ManyToMany relations join table is necessary.

```
SELECT * FROM USER_GROUP_MAP;
GROUP_ID    USER_ID  
4            1
4            2
4            3
```

This is the result with the code you have posted.You should override hashcode and equals method in both the entity classes in order to avoid duplication of data in the tables.

Code used for testing the above relationship mappings.

```
@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent applicationEvent) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setName("Damian");
    userRepository.save(user);

    user = new User();
    user.setName("Marta");
    userRepository.save(user);

    user = new User();
    user.setName("Natalia");
    userRepository.save(user);

    UGroup uGroup = new UGroup();
    uGroup.setName("Mieszkanie");
    uGroup = uGroupRepository.save(uGroup);

    user = userRepository.findById(1).get();
    user.addGroup(uGroup);
    user = userRepository.save(user);

    // unable to execute

    user = userRepository.findById(2).get();
    user.addGroup(uGroupRepository.findById(4).get());
    user = userRepository.save(user);


    // unable to execute 2

    uGroup = uGroupRepository.findById(4).get();
    uGroup.addUser(userRepository.findById(3).get());
    uGroup = uGroupRepository.save(uGroup);

}
```

Comment: I executed your code.
It doesn't work for me... :-(
I overrited equals and hashCode methods, after run I receive: `Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_C ON PUBLIC.USER_GROUP_MAP(GROUP_ID, USER_ID) VALUES 1"; SQL statement:
insert into user_group_map (group_id, user_id) values (?, ?) [23505-199]`

Comment: Seems you are associating duplicate entries in the USER_GROUP_MAP table.Hibernate is trying to insert duplicate row for the same association.Also exclude Ids from the equals code as in this case id is surrogate keys.

Comment: Yep, I know, I googled this error before comment, but H2 database is created each time with program run, so the database is definitely empty.
Class with data load is runned one time.
I don't hava idea what schould i do.

Comment: Since onApplicationEvent is tried to spring's lifecycle the data might be getting inserted twice.Try to debug this method to check whether it is called twice.

Comment: I have added testing code it seems there is a bug in the code due to which same group reference is stored twice.I have rectified the answer.

Comment: Hurra It works :-D Thanks a lot. 
Additionally I observed that using lookbook sometimes cause StackOverflowError, so I must forget about use it :-(